TensorFlow converting model to google coral TPU compatible
I'm trying to learn some model to better recognize object in my camera(frigate). I prepared some training data and take code from tutorial. It looks promising but now i have a problem with converting my model to TFlight(with integer quantization) as i need to do that before compilation for coral tpu(at least this is what i found in internet). Could you help me with conversion problem. I'm fighting with it couple days and can't make it working.
This is my current error:
 Total params: 2,259,265 (8.62 MB)
 Trainable params: 1,281 (5.00 KB)
 Non-trainable params: 2,257,984 (8.61 MB)
4/4 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2s 211ms/step - accuracy: 0.8043 - loss: 0.5318
initial loss: 0.53
initial accuracy: 0.81
Epoch 1/5
7/7 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 5s 194ms/step - accuracy: 0.7013 - loss: 0.6271 - val_accuracy: 0.8077 - .............................
Epoch 5/5
7/7 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 83ms/step - accuracy: 0.8150 - loss: 0.5426 - val_accuracy: 0.8173 - val_loss: 0.4871
Error converting model:  'Functional' object has no attribute '_get_save_spec'

and my app code
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import tensorflow as tf

BATCH_SIZE = 32
IMG_SIZE = (160, 160)

train_dir = os.path.abspath("./test/train")
validation_dir = os.path.abspath("./test/validation")

train_dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(train_dir,
                                                            shuffle=True,
                                                            batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                                            image_size=IMG_SIZE)

validation_dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(validation_dir,
                                                                 shuffle=True,
                                                                 batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                                                 image_size=IMG_SIZE)

class_names = train_dataset.class_names

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
for images, labels in train_dataset.take(1):
  for i in range(9):
    ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
    plt.title(class_names[labels[i]])
    plt.axis("off")

val_batches = tf.data.experimental.cardinality(validation_dataset)
test_dataset = validation_dataset.take(val_batches // 5)
validation_dataset = validation_dataset.skip(val_batches // 5)

print('Number of validation batches: %d' % tf.data.experimental.cardinality(validation_dataset))
print('Number of test batches: %d' % tf.data.experimental.cardinality(test_dataset))

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

train_dataset = train_dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
validation_dataset = validation_dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
test_dataset = test_dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip('horizontal'),
  tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation(0.2),
])

for image, _ in train_dataset.take(1):
  plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
  first_image = image[0]
  for i in range(9):
    ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
    augmented_image = data_augmentation(tf.expand_dims(first_image, 0))
    plt.imshow(augmented_image[0] / 255)
    plt.axis('off')

preprocess_input = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.preprocess_input

rescale = tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./127.5, offset=-1)

# Create the base model from the pre-trained model MobileNet V2
IMG_SHAPE = IMG_SIZE + (3,)
base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                               include_top=False,
                                               weights='imagenet')

image_batch, label_batch = next(iter(train_dataset))
feature_batch = base_model(image_batch)
print(feature_batch.shape)

base_model.trainable = False

# Let's take a look at the base model architecture
base_model.summary()

global_average_layer = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
feature_batch_average = global_average_layer(feature_batch)
print(feature_batch_average.shape)

prediction_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
prediction_batch = prediction_layer(feature_batch_average)
print(prediction_batch.shape)

inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(160, 160, 3))
x = data_augmentation(inputs)
x = preprocess_input(x)
x = base_model(x, training=False)
x = global_average_layer(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
outputs = prediction_layer(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

model.summary()

len(model.trainable_variables)

tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True)

base_learning_rate = 0.0001
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=base_learning_rate),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(threshold=0.5, name='accuracy')])

initial_epochs = 5

loss0, accuracy0 = model.evaluate(validation_dataset)

print("initial loss: {:.2f}".format(loss0))
print("initial accuracy: {:.2f}".format(accuracy0))

history = model.fit(train_dataset,
                    epochs=initial_epochs,
                    validation_data=validation_dataset)

# Convert the saved model to TensorFlow Lite
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]

try:
    quantized_tflite_model = converter.convert()
    print("Model converted successfully")
except Exception as e:
    print("Error converting model: ", e) <--- HERE ERROR


acc = history.history['accuracy']
val_acc = history.history['val_accuracy']

loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(acc, label='Training Accuracy')
plt.plot(val_acc, label='Validation Accuracy')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.ylim([min(plt.ylim()),1])
plt.title('Training and Validation Accuracy')

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(loss, label='Training Loss')
plt.plot(val_loss, label='Validation Loss')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.ylabel('Cross Entropy')
plt.ylim([0,1.0])
plt.title('Training and Validation Loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.show()

Tried also
    converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
    converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
    converter.representative_dataset = train_dataset
    #The below 3 lines performs the input - output quantization
    converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
    converter.inference_input_type = tf.uint8
    converter.inference_output_type = tf.uint8

but got Error converting model:  'Functional' object has no attribute '_get_save_spec' 

Hi @skoczo,The error 'Functional' object has no attribute '_get_save_spec' indicates a potential issue with accessing or saving the model prior to conversion. Verify that you are using compatible versions of TensorFlow and TensorFlow Lite, as conversion issues can arise from version mismatches. Ensure that the model is saved in the SavedModel format before attempting conversion, and load it properly for the conversion process.
